# Applying for Schengen with someone else as sponsor

Tags: visas, schengen, schengen-visas

I have to apply for schengen visa in Netherland embassy. My dad will be funding my travel. What additional documents do i need to attach with application.
Note: Going for summer school.

Answer (score 1):

- You will have to make it credible that you are a **tourist** who will return home when your visa is up, and not overstay. This can be difficult for a young person. Document your current and future education. And you should document **your** financial situation, even if you do not pay for the travel yourself.
- You will have to make it credible that your Dad is giving you the money as a *gift* and not as an investment. That means you have to demonstrate that he can reasonably afford the expense.

Comment: I'm going to attend a summer school for 9 days. Does that make any difference. Edited the question as well. Sorry.

Comment: @user300778, no matter if it is one day or three months, you will have to convince the visa officials that you will go back afterwards. Going to school will help to make the premise of your trip appear reasonable.